# call visits count in place of comments

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I'm using [this plugin](http://plugin.saragna.com/vc-addon/) on WordPress and I need to change the way it's works the "order by comments" and change it to "order by views". I'm using this [other plugin](https://github.com/cabrerahector/wordpress-popular-posts) for the views, so I'm trying to figure out how to make this work.

I found these lines on the carrousel plugin

```
case 'comment_count':

    $order_value=wp_count_comments($post->id);

    $order_value=$order_value->total_comments;

break;
```

So I tried to change it using the [variables of the Popular Posts plugin](https://github.com/cabrerahector/wordpress-popular-posts/blob/master/public/class-wordpress-popular-posts-public.php)

```
case 'comment_count':

    $order_value=update_views_count($post->id);

    $order_value=$order_value->views;

break;
```

But of course, it didn't work because I don't really get this, and the posts on the carousel are not ordered by visits.

I thought in this idea because I have just basic knowledge about php and I don't know how to implement the order by visits on the carousel I'm using.

Comment: The VC Addons plugin is a paid one so no one can see its source code without buying it. Have you tried contacting the developer directly to ask them how to sort posts by views count?

Comment: Why are you trying to call `update_views_count`? That is the method to _record/track_ a view - you want to _read_ the current values. If this plugin doesn’t have a convenience method to get the current view count for a post, then your best bet is probably to read that from the tables the plugin uses to record its data yourself.

Comment: @cabrerahector oh you are right, no one can see anything, but I think the thing is with the other plugin. i tried to contact the developer in the past, but he is really useless

Comment: @misorude I took the method from the Popular Posts plugin, wich it has methods to get everything about views, but I don't know how to use tins in place of the comments thing

Comment: @misorude WPP does have a helper function to retrieve the views count: [wpp_get_views()](https://github.com/cabrerahector/wordpress-popular-posts/wiki/2.-Template-tags#wpp_get_views) (disclosure: I'm the developer of the WPP plugin, I happened to stumble into this topic by chance). However, without knowing how the VC Addons plugin works (source code) OP is going to have a hard time figuring this one out.

Comment: The snippet shown above only seems to require the order value for a single post at this point, so I guess something like `$order_value=wpp_get_views($post->id, false, false);` should work …?

Comment: Sounds like it. @Dario please give that a try and let us know.

Comment: @misorude I'm afraid it didn't work :(
I replaced the "update_views_count" with your line but the order on the carousel is not by visits
There's no way I can give you guys more of the source code, right?

Comment: Nope. Distributing private code in public would be a problem. You either ask the developer for help or hire someone else to do the work for you. Alternatively, you could just customize the WPP plugin to have it display a grid of posts. It's not that difficult and the plugin is open source too so anyone can help you.

Comment: @cabrerahector yeah I know I do that, but the idea is to avoid all that. I think I can make this work, is about to modify the correct line, that's all.
There must be some variable or function in the WPP to use, I mean, the posts are already organize by views, I just need to take that info and use it